# Where is the USA's report on enhanced interrogation techniques located?

Tags: united-states

I'm writing an assignment about torture in first world countries(or torture "executed" by them).

I've been looking for the report on Enhanced Interrogation Techniques, written after 9/11, which was released recently.

Does anybody know where I can find it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could try asking your senator or representative.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is just a link, but since all you're asking for is the report itself, here is the recent [CIA Torture Report](http://www.intelligence.senate.gov/study2014/sscistudy1.pdf).

[Another copy, in case the first link dies](http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2014/12/09/here-is-the-cia-torture-report).

Comment: But that's the redacted one...

Comment: I don't think the unredacted one is available. If it is, it's probably on bittorrent or wikileaks, but I'm not finding it. There are recent stories (including 4 days ago) that seem to indicate that the unredacted one is still unavailable to the public.

Comment: You would need a clearance and it would not be available on the public internet. If you have Siprnet or jwics access, and authorization you'll know what to do.